# Do additional, duplicate flags help get a problem post sorted sooner or create duplicate work?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags

If I come across a post that I know another user has already flagged as off topic or some other issue (usually by comments left) and if I submit the same flag does it add weight to the suggested close reason getting the issue resolved sooner or does it create additional entries in the queues that wastes reviewers' time?

Am I helping clean or creating more work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does neither.  Additional flags don't help close the post any sooner, nor does it create any additional entries in the queue.  Additional flags *do* affect whether or not a given review entry will age out of the queue, but that's it.  So you're neither helping, nor wasting anyone's time but your own.

Comment: What about the case where: user1 flags as "it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" and user2 flags as "unclear what you're asking". Do these flags get aggregated or is the post just generically marked for review and placed in the Close Queue?

Comment: @indivisible The review item will indicate all of the close flags on that post, not just the first.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I'll continue on as before, flagging where I see fit safe in the knowledge I'm not bloating the queues any more than needs be.